# @parcel/core: No transformers found for .glb file

Tags: javascript, deployment, vercel, parceljs

I'm getting this error when I deploy my parcel.js to Vercel:

```
@parcel/core: No transformers found for static/actions.glb.
```

Here's the full deployment logs from Vercel:

```
Detected package.json
Installing dependencies...
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
npm WARN deprecated highlight.js@7.3.0: Version no longer supported. Upgrade to @latest
added 27 packages in 3s
154 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Building...
 Build failed.
@parcel/core: No transformers found for static/actions.glb.
  /vercel/path0/node_modules/@parcel/config-default/index.json:3:3
     2 |   "bundler": "@parcel/bundler-default",
  >  3 |   "transformers": {
  >    |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  4 |     "types:*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/transformer-typescript-types"],
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  5 |     "bundle-text:*": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-inline-string"],
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  6 |     "data-url:*": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-inline-string"],
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  7 |     "worklet:*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  8 |       "@parcel/transformer-worklet",
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  >  9 |       "..."
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 10 |     ],
  >    | ^^^^^^
  > 11 |     "*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 12 |       "@parcel/transformer-babel",
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 13 |       "@parcel/transformer-js",
  >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Command "parcel build index.html" exited with 1
```

But when I run `parcel build index.html` in my directory locally, it's completely successful:
[image]

Any ideas why it's not working on Vercel, but building locally? I'm using [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy) and all my GLB files are in there and in my dist.

[image]

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "vercel --prod",
    "vercel-build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^3.9.1",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
    "static": "^2.0.0",
    "three": "^0.136.0",
    "vercel": "^23.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^4.1.11",
    "parcel-plugin-static-files-copy": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First add a `.parcelrc` file in your project root folder, then add this into :

```json
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "transformers": {
        "*.glb": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"]
    }
}
```

Don't forget to restart your Parcel script.

*Working for me using Parcel 2.4.0*

Comment: Thanks for this.. nice to know there is no need to hack node_modules \@parcel\config_default to achieve the same + warnings.. just successfully added that raw transformer for my .txt files :p