# @parcel/core: No transformers found for .exr file

Tags: three.js, bundler, parcel

I'm using **parcel bundler** to run my three-js project and I'm importing **EXRLoader** from `three/examples/jsm/loaders/EXRLoader` but I'm getting this error:

```
@parcel/core: No transformers found for ani-tiles.exr.
\node_modules\@parcel\config-default\index.json:3:3

   2 |   "bundler": "@parcel/bundler-default",
>  3 |   "transformers": {
>    |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  4 |     "types:*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/transformer-typescript-types"],
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  5 |     "bundle-text:*": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-inline-string"],
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  6 |     "data-url:*": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-inline-string"],
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  7 |     "worklet:*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  8 |       "@parcel/transformer-worklet",
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>  9 |       "..."
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^
> 10 |     ],
>    | ^^^^^^
> 11 |     "*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 12 |       "@parcel/transformer-babel",
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 13 |       "@parcel/transformer-js",
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried reloading parcel and a bunch of other stuff, but nothing is helping.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70487267/12302691) is very similar to my problem. I created a *.parcelrc* file with the code:

```json
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.{gltf,glb,png,jpg,obj,exr}": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"]
  }
}
```